# Difference between asp.net mvc Selector and Filter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filter, selector

I am confused about asp.net mvc seletor & filter.

As we know, there are 5 types of filters: authentication, authorization, action, result, exception.

However, there is another 'filter': action selector.

Base classes are different as well: ActionMethodSelectorAttribute and FilterAttribute

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between selector & common filter?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action selectors simply determine which action to run (e.g. by the HTTP verb used for the request).

Filters some different goals - Action Filters run code before or after an action, exception filters runs code on exception, authentication filters are used for code realted to authentication, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know they are in different scopes. Action selectors are just a kind of normal attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Today i just red a material which illustrate this related question.

Inside the mvc framework, it goes something like this:
----ControllerFactory
----Controller selected and instantiated (With the help of Dependency Resolver)
----Call controller.Execute(RequestContext)
--------ActionInvoker (default: ControllerActionInvoker)
--------this.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext, actionName)
------------Choose the action method (action selectors involved)
------------authentication & authorization filters
------------model binding
------------invoke action with action filters
------------authentication challenge (IAuthenticationFilter)
------------Execute result with result filters
----Controller dispose

See, the selector and filter are totally in different scope, even though they both are used in actionInvoker.